# How to access ~/Library from network booted OSX

Tags: macos

Would you tell me How to access ~/Library of my local disk from network booted OSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"~/Library" is the short path for "/Users/UserName/Library" where "UserName" is the name of the user.

"/Users/UserName/Library" is the short path for "/Volumes/VolumeName/Users/UserName/Library" where "VolumeName" is the name of the volume.

"/Volumes/VolumeName/Users/UserName/Library" is the **full path** of a user library.

If you want to access a user library from a different volume than the start / boot volume, then you must use the full path.

Select "Go To Folder" in the "Go" menu of the Finder, enter the full path and confirm.

Please note that you might get a permission error if you (aka the current user) do not have access to this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Finder window and then navigate to the Home folder. That’s the one represented by the cute little house icon over in the sidebar. If you don’t see it, click on something like the Desktop or Documents folder, and then Command-click on the title bar of the window. You’ll get a drop-down menu that shows the file path of the current folder, which–if you’ve picked a folder from your Home directory–will show the Home folder somewhere in the list. Click on it to go to the Home folder.

Now, once you’re there, hit Command-J to bring up the View Options panel. You’ll see a checkbox to “Show Library Folder” somewhere in that panel, depending on the view your Finder window is in. Simply check it to show your User account’s Library folder. Now you can go in there and mess around to your heart’s content.